# Re-Center Webpage in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have custom built CSS for me but am no longer in contact with the creator.  I wanted to make a div (#rightcolumn) bigger by 55px. I did this by making iframe in the div bigger and it auto expands for me.  However the banner, (#topsection), became a little short - so I had to add 55px to that to make it 1255px width.

Now page is off center some.  When I try to edit other float commands to fix, the div's end up all over.  I've tried for a few days. If anyone could help now with re-centering this. I would really appreciate.

Test page: [Serious Sports Bigger](http://serioussportstv.net/bigger.php)
Link to css: [CSS link](http://serioussportstv.net/content/style/newsite.css)
New Css

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    line-height:1.5em;
    background:#C0C0C0;
}
b {
    font-size:110%;
}
em {
    color:red;
}
#maincontainer {
    width:1200px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#topsection {
    background:#191919;
    height:90px;
    width:1255px
}
#contentwrapper {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
#contentcolumn {
    margin:0 360px 0 180px;
    color:#F1F1F1;
}
#leftcolumn {
    float:left;
    width:180px;
    margin-left:-1200px;
    background:#C8FC98;
}
#rightcolumn {
    float:left;
    width:355px;
    margin-left:-355px;
    background:#E5E5E5;
}
#footer {
    clear:left;
    width:100%;
    background:#191919;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    padding:4px 0;
}
#footer a {
    color:#62C301;
}
.innertube {
    margin:10px;
    margin-top:0;
}
.arrowgreen {
    width:180px;
    border-style:solid solid none solid;
    border-color:#94AA74;
    border-size:1px;
    border-width:1px;
}
.arrowgreen ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.arrowgreen li a {
    font:bold 12px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display:block;
    background:transparent url(http://i39.tinypic.com/2r2rhnc.gif) 100% 0;
    height:24px;
    padding:4px 0 4px 10px;
    line-height:24px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.arrowgreen li a:link, .arrowgreen li a:visited {
    color:#5E7830;
}
.arrowgreen li a:hover {
    color:#26370A;
    background-position:100% -32px;
}
.arrowgreen li a.selected {
    color:#26370A;
    background-position:100% -64px;
}
```

Comment: i frame sounds like a bad idea

Comment: I think you should hire a web developer to do this for you. These are simple tasks for someone who has learnt css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the **CSS** is being applied twice, you will need to look into that.

Just apply the following **CSS**:

```
#maincontainer {
    width: 1255px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#contentwrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 1200px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm it seems by adding that I do not get the same results as you. Could you perhaps check the test page now?

Thanks so much for your help. I'm no real web developer, just a guy trying to help others.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

You also have to change DOCTYPE to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this:

```
body {
    margin : 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`#maincontainer` is only `1200px;`, your contents are overflowing. Solution:

```
#maincontainer{
  width:1255px; margin:0 auto;
}
```